# Am I using the best SQLAlchemy query?

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I've got an Opportunity table and an Owner table. The Opportunity table has a many to one relationship with Owner. I'm using Python, SQLAlchemy, FLask-Alchemy and SQLite on this project. I need to do an inner join on the Opportunity table against the Owner table and return a single result set (with fields from both tables).

I need to build a dictionary out of the result set so that I can easily generate Json. The following code all works... but... It took a ton of debugging to figure out how to transform the result set returned (which, in this case is a generator object) into a dictionary.

Did I make this harder than I needed to? Is there a better way to do this using SQLAlchemy? (such as using the expression language instead of the ORM)

```
owner = db.session.query(Owner).filter(Owner.id == owner_id).first()
if owner is None:
    return None

result = {'data': []}
report_date = datetime.datetime.strptime('2016-05-01', '%Y-%m-%d')

rows = db.session.query(Opportunity)\
                 .filter(Opportunity.status == 'Won',
                         Opportunity.owner == owner,
                         or_(Opportunity.actual_close_date_iso_year_week == '2016/16',\
                             Opportunity.actual_close_date_iso_year_week == '2016/17'),
                         Opportunity.report_date == report_date)\
                 .order_by(Opportunity.account)\
                 .join(Owner, Owner.id == Opportunity.owner_id)\
                 .values(Opportunity.account,
                         Opportunity.report_date_iso_year_week,
                         Opportunity.report_date,
                         Owner.first_name)

for row in rows:
    result_row = {}
    fields = getattr(row, '_fields')
    for field in fields:
        result_row[field] = getattr(row, field)
    result['data'].append(result_row)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that basically this is the way to get what you need, however I would suggest few minor changes:

- You don't really need to join, as after `.filter(Opportunity.owner==owner)` all the rows that you get from the Opportunity table have the same `owner_id`.
- I think it's better to define the list of needed fields once, instead of trying to get it from each row tuple.

So, the code may be like this:

```
required_fields = ('account','report_date_iso_year_week','report_date')
owner = db.session.query(Owner).filter(Owner.id == owner_id).first()
if owner is None:
    return None

result = {'data': []}
report_date = datetime.datetime.strptime('2016-05-01', '%Y-%m-%d')

rows = db.session.query(Opportunity)\
                 .filter(Opportunity.status == 'Won',
                         Opportunity.owner == owner,
                         or_(Opportunity.actual_close_date_iso_year_week == '2016/16',\
                             Opportunity.actual_close_date_iso_year_week == '2016/17'),
                         Opportunity.report_date == report_date)\
                 .order_by(Opportunity.account)\
                 .values(*[getattr(Opportunity,f) for f in required_fields])

for row in rows:
    result_row = {'first_name':owner.first_name}
    for field in required_fields:
        result_row[field] = getattr(row, field)
    result['data'].append(result_row)
```

Comment: Very interesting techniques. What would  you about including fields from the Owner table if its fields weren't available in the routine? (ie, in product I'll pass in an owner_id for the filter value)?

Comment: urim, your suggestions got me pointed in the right direction. Here's what I ended up with: http://rogerpence.github.io/python-libretto/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy-join-tests-single.html